# Creating MPEG-4 Samples in Java

Tags: java, mpeg

I am trying to create a 30 second sample from a 2 minute MPEG-4 video. We are looking for a 100% java solution as an alternative to ffmpeg.  So far, we have tried IsoParser, which lacks example code and documentation splitting MPEG-4.  Has anyone used this tool or others to create cut/split MPEG-4 video?

Answer (score 3):

Or use [Xuggler](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler); it's free, open-source (LGPL), maintained, and does stuff like that in its sleep.  See the [tutorials](http://wiki.xuggle.com/MediaTool_Introduction) link for lots of examples.

Answer (score 0):

IBM has a thing: http://www.alphaworks.ibm.com/tech/tk4mpeg4

Comment: The page says that It has "graduated" any Idea where the new page is or what happened?

Comment: I think it's here now: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-mpeg4/ Check the bottom of the page for the download link.